# Knockout bind optional fields

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind a JSON containing optional fields using knockout js.
The problem is I keep getting this error:

> Unable to process binding "value: function..."

And I can't add the missing fields as I need them to remain missing (the missing fields are taken from a "parent" JSON)

Is there any option to tell knockout js to ignore those fields and only add them if a user types anything in the field?

Comment: Any chance we could get a jsfiddle or plunkr of your problem?

Comment: It's quite complicated.
I made a simple example: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hrfq3wdh/1/)

The idea is sometimes I have a full JSON and sometimes I have partial.
I mustn't add empty fields unless the user intend to add the field (It's a child/parent inheritance mechanism)

Comment: If you click on "apply Full" - It will work. I just need that "apply Partial" will ignore the missing field and create it if the user type something in the input field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to a non-existent view-model property if you use the property syntax, like `$data.property`.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.key">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrfq3wdh/2/

Answer (score 1):

can you just use hasOwnProperty?

```
var data = {
  foo1: 'bar1',
  foo3: 'bar3'
}


function viewModel(mydata) {
  var self = this;
  this.foo1 = ko.observable(mydata.foo1);
  this.foo2 = ko.observable(mydata.hasOwnProperty('foo2') ? mydata.foo2 : '');
  this.foo3 = ko.observable(mydata.foo3);

}


var vm = new viewModel(data);


(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
})(jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/8/

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your answer. It will work but I need to translate the JSON to a ko observables and i have more than 40 fields in a complex hierarchical structure.
Is there any simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe another possibility would be to use the ko mapping plugin and the with data binding run snippet below.

```js
var partial = {value : 456};
var full = { key: "abc", 
             value : 123};
             
function viewModel() {
var self = this;
this.full=ko.observable('');
this.partial=ko.observable('');
this.applyFull = function(){
    self.full(ko.mapping.fromJS(full));
    self.partial('');
  }
 this.applyPartial = function(){
     self.full('');
     self.partial(ko.mapping.fromJS(partial));
  }
}
     

var vm = new viewModel();

(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: full">
  Key <input type="text" data-bind="value: key"> Value <input type="text" data-bind="value: value">
</div>
<div data-bind="with: partial">
  Value <input type="text" data-bind="value: value">
</div>

<button data-bind="click: applyFull"> apply Full </button>
<button data-bind="click: applyPartial"> apply Partial </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are good but too complex to implement on my small system.

It appears the problem was trying to access to a field inside innere object which doesn't exists. (for example, `main.inner.price` when inner is undefined)
I ended up creating an empty object whenever it's missing in the main object  using `main.inner = main.inner || {}`